# Rounding to two decimal places is not working

Tags: t-sql, random, decimal, rounding

I am trying to reduce the decimal places of my number to two. Unfortunately is not possible. For this reason I added some of my code, maybe you will see the mistake...

```
Update [dbo].[company$Line] SET
Amount = ROUND((SELECT RAND(1) * Amount),2),
...
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[company$Line]
```

Amount in db which I want to change:

```
0.00000000000000000000
1914.65000000000010000000
376.81999999999999000000
289.23000000000002000000
```

Result I get after executing the code:

```
0.00000000000000000000
1366.28000000000000000000
268.89999999999998000000
206.38999999999999000000
```

Result I want to get (or something like this):

```
0.00000000000000000000                  or 0.00
1366.30000000000000000000               or 1366.30
268.99000000000000000000                or 268.99
206.49000000000000000000                or 206.49
```

Comment: What is the type of the `Amount` column?  Note that not all numeric types in SQL Server are exact.  Also, I might recommend _not_ updating with a rounded value, but instead just calling `ROUND` when you want to display your data a certain way.

Comment: The type of `Amount` is decimal. All numeric fields in my table are decimal.

Comment: @joknawe I tried your solution, but I am getting an error.. Incorrect syntax near ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAND()` returns float.
According to [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the result of multiplying decimal and float is float, try:

```
ROUND(CAST(RAND(1) as decimal(28,12)) * Amount, 2)
```

this should do the trick.